# reCaptcha with form based authentication in java

Tags: java, jsp, recaptcha

I have simple login form, which is pased to j_security_check for authentication.

```
                <form id="loginForm" action="j_security_check" method="post">
                  <input type="text" id="username" name="j_username" class="form-control" placeholder="Email" required /> <br />
                  <input type="password" id="password" name="j_password" class="form-control" placeholder="Heslo" required /> <br />

                  <input type="button" value="Zpět" />
                  <input type="submit" value="Přihlásit" />
                </form>
```

I want to add Google reCaptcha to the form, but I don´t know, how to solve the server side of the captcha, because the form is sent to j_security_check and nothing like my own servlet for authentication, where I would do whatever I would need.

Any idea how to solve this? Or is the concept wrong and I can´t get recaptcha and java form based authentication to work together?

Answer (score 0):

It is possible. You can create a bin that will be called when the form is submitted that can validate the catpcha. You can see this article here https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/glxce.html